# TEM wave propagating in two directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I learned that the electric and magnetic field of a TEM wave cannot have components parallel in the direction of travel. I am working on a problem in which the TEM wave has a component in the $z$ direction but travels in the $x$ and $y$ directions. I used a well-known formula to calculate the electric field from the magnetic field and ended up with a magnetic field that has a component in the direction of propagation, which should not be the case. How can this be ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither $\vec{E}$ nor $\vec{H}$ has a component in the direction of propagation $\hat k$. Not sure why you think they do. Note that $\vec{H}·\vec{k}=0$ and $\vec{E}·\vec{k}=0$.